# Given a public key in hexadecimal, how can I get an .asc file?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, hexadecimal

Given a public key in hexadecimal or base 64, how can I generate an .asc file for use with PGP programs?

For example, let's say I have someone's RSA public key, in hexadecimal:

```
04 40 ad 77 10 45 08 f2 3a ae 1d 1d 95 22 2f b3 f5 e5 2f da db 8c 39 3a 03 15 fb 4b 36 28 46 de 7b 00 f4 73 11 ae b9 ac 00 aa 19 34 6d fb 7c 56 b1 93 c0 1b 86 7c d0 a2 0b 4d 22 a9 d2 4d b0 f6 34 c4
```

How can I turn this number into a standard public key file (e.g. `.asc`)?

From what I understand, RSA takes in plaintext (any data) and the receiver's public key (a long number) and outputs ciphertext. So I shouldn't need anything more than this number to send an encrypted message.

---

I am trying to use the X.509 key on a VCard to send an encrypted email.

I haven't been able to find a program yet that can do this and `gpg --import` shows `no valid OpenPGP data found`

Comment: does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440978/how-do-you-generate-an-asc-file-from-pgp-public-key

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see anything there that does. I'm comfortable exporting a key from GPG, but I can't even get the key into GPG in the first place. Do you know how you take the raw binary data of a key and import it into GPG?

Comment: I haven't messed with keys for ages.. and I barely ever used pgp/gpg. But,  when I have used ssh keys i've had no issues and I could get things imported between ssh and another program..  I have also messed with binary re xxd. .  so I have some familiarity with these key things.   With keys you never need to tough the binary. Look, here's an example of a PGP key https://www.igolder.com/pgp/generate-key/   here's an example of an SSH key https://www.wpoven.com/tools/create-ssh-key#   Those guys at the Stackexchange link say you can rename a file as ASC...

Comment: I suppose you haev to consider.. what format is the original key that you want to use with GPG!  Also, when i'm using a particular program e.g. SSH, and it  uses a particular format of key I tend to generate it with SSH. I don't tend to try to convert some other format of key. So, why are you trying to convert your key to a PGP key.. What is the program that made the key?

Comment: also there are different types of key e.g. RSA vs DSA.  It might help you if you know something about the original key, like the exact format of it and how if at all PGP deals with that format

Comment: I don't have access to the program that generated it.  I just have a digital contact card with a X.509 key that I'm trying to send encrypted email to.

Comment: I don't know much about this X.509 thing but judging by this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480846/x-509-private-public-key  it looks like X.509 is not a key format, it's a "certificate" format, and whatever a "cerificate" is, it is a thing that contains a key or keys. So, e.g. it can contain an RSA key  So  if my findings there are all correct, you maybe want to extract the key from the X.509 certificate

Comment: I have already extracted the RSA public key. The problem is it is just a number (in hex), not a `.asc`. My question is: how do I convert that number into a `.asc` file?

Comment: The problem is, even if you create a working .asc file and use PGP, what is the _recipient_ going to do? Are they going to create an .asc file from their private key by hand, too?

Comment: @user1686: The key was included in a digital contact card (`KEY;X509;ENCODING=BASE64:...`), so surely they expect people to encrypt communications using it?

Comment: @Zaz: It was included not as a raw public key, but **as an X.509 certificate** (hence `X509`), therefore they also expect it to be used in the form of an X.509 certificate, which implies communications encrypted **in the S/MIME format**. Not in the form of a PGP certificate for PGP/MIME, nor anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand, RSA takes in plaintext (any data) and the receiver's public key (a long number) and outputs ciphertext. So I shouldn't need anything more than this number to send an encrypted message.

*Technically* yes, if you do everything "by hand", and if you expect the recipient to un-do everything by hand. But even then, there are several problems already.

First, RSA only takes *very short* plaintexts. You can't use it to encrypt a whole email message. (It depends on the key size, and on the padding that's used, which you [*have to*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84277/4941) use for RSA encryption to be secure, but) the general usage is that one would never use RSA to directly encrypt the real data – one would *always* use it in "hybrid mode" where AES (or similar) encrypts the plaintext, and RSA only encrypts the AES key.

So in practice you need to agree with the recipient on what RSA padding to use, what symmetric cipher to use, which block cipher mode to use (if applicable), which MAC scheme to use, what order to apply operations in (e.g. encrypt-then-MAC), etc.

One of the reasons for using "Standard public key files" like `.asc` (which holds OpenPGP certificates) or `.pem`/`.crt` (which holds X.509 certificates) is that these systems already have these things figured out. When you have an .asc file and give it to PGP software like GnuPG, it won't use raw RSA, it's already designed to use hybrid mode.

---

> I am trying to use the X.509 key on a VCard to send an encrypted email.

The second thing is that **you already *had* a standard public key file** – you had a perfectly fine X.509 certificate in the vCard (i.e. a `.crt` file), ready to use for encryption using the S/MIME or CMS standard. There is no need to extract its public key and create a whole new file – chances are, your mail app can import the X.509 certificate straight from the vCard and even automatically use it for encryption.

(The popular GnuPG suite comes with an `gpgsm` tool that takes X.509 certificates and does S/MIME encryption/decryption just like `gpg` does PGP.)

And related to that: if you were sent an X.509 certificate, this *very* strongly implies that the recipient **expects you to encrypt messages in the S/MIME format.** Suppose you extracted the RSA public key (modulus) anyway, and then used some tooling to put it in an .asc file – that is, an OpenPGP certificate – and proceeded to send an email message encrypted in the PGP format. The recipient would not be able to decrypt it, either because their email software doesn't recognize PGP/MIME in the first place (many apps only do S/MIME), or because it knows it can't match up a PGP message with an X.509 private keypair anyway (even people who use both PGP and S/MIME will almost universally have different keypairs for both).

(Well, technically they *could* decrypt it by going through the same procedure as you did, by converting their X.509 certificate and private key into the OpenPGP equivalents – but why *would* they bother doing so, I don't really know. And again, this is something they would need to *know about doing* – i.e. just like ciphers to use, it's another parameter that needs to be agreed on.)

---

> How can I turn this number into a standard public key file (e.g. .asc)?

For completeness, *is* it even possible to take an existing raw RSA public key and wrap it in a PGP or X.509 certificate? Yes, *almost,* but not quite. There are even more problems here.

First, for PGP there isn't much tooling that could be used that way. (And surprisingly, PGP is the more complex format out of the two, so I wouldn't try doing it by hand.) If I had to, then I'd probably start with the Sequoia library.

Going the other way around and creating X.509 certificates is technically an easier task, as the format is "just" ASN.1, so I'd use either Ruby's Net::OpenSSL or Python's python-certbuilder or something similar. It's actually a common task because that's how CAs issue certificates in the first place – they already need to copy the raw pubkey from a .csr into a fresh certificate before they sign it.

That leads to the second problem. If you're crafting an X.509 certificate, something has to *sign* that certificate for your S/MIME programs to accept it. It can't be "self-signed" because you don't have the private key for that, so you'll need to make your own internal S/MIME CA certificate for that purpose.

And if you're crafting a PGP certificate, it's a bit harder because its sub-packets *must* be self-signed by the same key (aka have "subkey binding signatures"), precisely to prevent someone from attaching fake user-IDs to your certificate, or distributing a real certificate with fake subkeys bundled. Without the corresponding private key, you will not succeed in making an `.asc` file that modern PGP tools will accept.

(It's much easier if you have the *private* key: you can import the X.509 keypair (.p12 or .pfx file) into gpgsm, which happens to share its private-key storage with gpg – then use gpg to "generate" a new PGP key in expert mode, and select the option to use an existing keypair when prompted. The program will then do everything for you.)

So about the only relevant standard format you *could* produce is a "semi-raw" PKCS#1 or PKCS#8 public key, the kind that the `openssl rsa` and `openssl pkey` tools deal with – it has no metadata, only the actual RSA modulus and exponent. Now this format could still be useful in some situations (and you don't even need to create such a file by hand – OpenSSL can pull it right out of an X.509 certificate if asked), e.g. perhaps you could use it with manual `openssl cms` invocation to create an S/MIME email message, but... you can just use the whole X.509 certificate to do the same thing.